# extract a specific field from attributes column of gff

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to extract `attributes` `Note` and `ID` information from a gff file. I loaded the GFF file using

```
library(ape)
GFF<-ape::read.gff(file = "gene_models.gff")
```

I want to do something like this to match for a dataset (produced from `DESeq2`) with the attributes column Note and ID:

```
Data <- GFF$attributes(ID)[match(DESeq2$seqid, GFF$attributes(Note))]
```

`DESeq2` was run:

```
salmon quant -i salmon_index -l A -1 input_R1_paired.fastq -2 input_R2_paired.fastq -o transcripts


library(GenomicFeatures)
library(tximport)
library(DESeq2)
library(AnnotationDbi)

dir <- "/path"
list.files(dir)

samples <- read.csv2("path",sep =";", header = TRUE)
head(samples)

my.files <-  list.files(list.dirs(path = ".", full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE), pattern = "quant.sf", full.names = TRUE)
my.files
names(my.files) <- sapply(strsplit(my.files, split="\\/"), function(x)x[2])
head(my.files, 6)
all(file.exists(my.files))

TxDb <- makeTxDbFromGFF(file = "gene_models.gff")
k <- keys(TxDb, keytype = "TXNAME")
tx2gene <- AnnotationDbi::select(TxDb, k, "GENEID", "TXNAME")
head(tx2gene)

txi <- tximport(files = my.files, type = "salmon", tx2gene = tx2gene)
head(txi$counts)

rownames(samples)<-samples$Run
colnames(txi$counts)
rownames(samples) <- colnames(txi$counts)

samples1 <- data.frame(Group= factor(rep(c("High", "Low"), each = 3)))
rownames(samples1) <- colnames(txi$counts)

ddsTxi <- DESeqDataSetFromTximport(txi, colData = samples1, design = ~ Group)                              
ddsTxi
ddsTxi <- DESeq(ddsTxi)

res <- results(ddsTxi)
head(results(ddsTxi, tidy=TRUE)) 
summary(res)
res <- res[order(res$padj),]
head(res)
write.csv(as.data.frame(res), file="res.csv")
```

And output file looks like:

```
seqid         baseMean    log2FoldChange   lfcSE   stat pvalue    padj
<character>  <numeric>  <numeric>  <numeric>  <numeric> <numeric <numeric>
1  G_06g024400.1 1266.29960801482 -3.27190177919055 0.493708714717401 -6.62719065241412 3.42135630989487e-11 6.20155044731545e-07
```

And `GFF` looks like:

```
seqid source type start   end score strand phase  attributes
1 G1.3ch00  maker gene 21882 22007    NA      -  <NA>  ID=G_06g024400.1;Name=G_06g024400.1;Note=Similar to 06g024400.1.1: LOW QUALITY:protein;ref_id=06g024400.1.1;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @akrun, I have added it in original question. Thank you!

Comment: I added the packages. Actually, the dput output is really large for both the datasets. Is there any other way that I use to show the required structure.

Comment: I have added all the packages and commands to produce DESeq2 output and load GFF file. Thank you

Comment: thanks, but the files are based on your input.  Sorry, may be somebody else who have worked on this would be able to help as I can't reproduce it

Comment: In case it helps, I have added the previous step using salmon to create quant.sf files from input RNA seq files which are then used in tximport and DESeq2.

Comment: let me try that. thanks for trying to create reproducible example